# Can an int object in Python become iterable inside a function?

Tags: python, int, iterable

I am trying to follow along the [blog post](http://machinelearningmastery.com/naive-bayes-classifier-scratch-python/) titled *How To Implement Naive Bayes From Scratch in Python*

And from the blog, this is the code for defining a function for separating a database by class type.

```
def separateByClass(dataset):
    separated = {}
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        vector = dataset[i]
        if (vector[-1] not in separated):
            separated[vector[-1]] = []
        separated[vector[-1]].append(vector)
    return separated
```

But I could not understand how `vector[-1]` is a right usage when `vector` is an `int` type object. If I try the same commands one by one outside the function, the line of code with `vector[-1]` obviously throws a `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`. Then how is it working inside the function?

Comment: Vectors are usually *tuples* of integers, depending on the number of dimensions.

Comment: Dataset is defined right below the code on the site you linked, `dataset = [[1,20,1], [2,21,0], [3,22,1]]`. It's not an int

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, integers do not become iterable, in functions or elsewhere.

However, the values in `dataset` *are not integers*. They are lists; the article defines the dataset in the next snippet:

```
dataset = [[1,20,1], [2,21,0], [3,22,1]]
```

so when iterating over the dataset, each `vector` is one of those lists (`[1, 20, 1]` first, then `[2, 21, 0]`, etc.) and `vector[-1]` is the last value in each of those lists.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was my mistake. To try this function, I created a dataset as a list of integers instead of a list of lists. I got that now. Thank you @martijn-pieters and all of you.

Answer (score 3):

In the example, `dataset[i]` is a list of lists:

```
dataset = [[1,20,1], [2,21,0], [3,22,1]]
```

That means, that `dataset[i]` is a list itself, for example:

```
dataset[0] = [1,20,1]
```

So `dataset[0][-1]` would be `1`, the last element of `dataset[0]`.